# Merging Multiple XSD files

Tags: xml, xsd

I have around 6 individual xsd schemas that define one complex type each. I want to create a master xsd schema and include all six of the xsd so that I can generate an xml document that can contain an element from each individual schema. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `<xs:import>` or `<xs:include>` to incorporate the six individual files into one "master" schema.

Be careful which of `<xs:import>` or `<xs:include>` you use, though, they're quite different in what they mean, but without knowing anything about your schema, I can't advise you which to use.